# bitwise operations

Tags: c, embedded, bit-manipulation, pic

```
// PWM frequency:
// 0 - 48 kHz
// 1 - 12 kHz
// 2 -  3 kHz
enum { MOTOR_FREQUENCY = 1 };

// Configure Timer 2 w. 250x period.
T2CON = 1 << 2 | MOTOR_FREQUENCY /* << 0 */;
```

Have i understood this right?

11111111 Arithmetic left-shift-by-two of 0 or 1 or 2

Means:

```
T2CON = 1 << 2 | 0 = 1111 1100    
T2CON = 1 << 2 | 1 = 1111 1000    
T2CON = 1 << 2 | 2 = 1111 0000
```

Kind Regards, Sonite

Comment: -I suggest you read this tut about bit manipulation http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=37871

-Also you would receive better answers if you ask your question in a microcontrollers specific forum .

Comment: Do you mean that i should have thrown the question at microchip forum instead?

Comment: I like seeing the occasional embedded question here, but some more context is always good (what core you're using) and what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think you will get more specific answers at PIC or AVR forums , so yeah I mean that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context:

`TCON2` is a timer register on PIC MCUs, where the last two bits configure the prescaler.

[image: TCON2 configuration register on PICs]

- `T2CKPS[1:0]` = `0b00` = 0 => /1 prescaler
- `T2CKPS[1:0]` = `0b01` = 1 => /4 prescaler
- `T2CKPS[1:0]` = `0b1x` = 2 or 3 => /16 prescaler

Bit 2 actually switches the timer on, so it always needs to be set to do anything, hence the `1 << 2` (which really should be written as `1 << T2CON_TMR2ON_bit` with `T2CON_TMR2ON_bit` being defined in some CPU-configuration header)

All said and done, the three settings are `0b100`, `0b101`, and `0b110`, which turn on the timer, and tweak the prescaler to get those frequencies mentioned in the comments.

Also, using an `enum` with one element is just about pointless; use `#define`.

Answer (score 4):

```
1 << 2 = 100b
```

So with the OR:

```
100b | 1 = 101b
100b | 2 = 110b
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are playing with a microcontroller with 8-bit registers .

```
0000 0001 << 2 = 0000 0100
then 
0000 0100 OR 0000 0000 = 0000 0100
-----
0000 0001 << 2 = 0000 0100
then 
0000 0100 OR 0000 0001 = 0000 0101
-----
0000 0001 << 2 = 0000 0100
then 
0000 0100 OR 0000 0010 = 0000 0110
```